# Flattr API for Java?

Tags: java, android, flattr

Is there an official (or otherwise well-maintained) Java library to use the Flattr API? Should work both server-side and on Android. For Android, is there a comfortable SSO-solution similar to what Facebook offers, where other apps can delegate authentication to the official app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [flattr4j](http://flattr4j.shredzone.org), which is actively maintained (by myself) and works both on server-side and on Android.